# Swift protocol default values are not changable

Tags: swift, protocols

I have such a protocol properties with default values. But with the current implementation if I create an instance of `AssetViewAttributes` with some other values for `avgPrice`, `precision` they still have the default values. How can I change them?

```
struct Crypto: AssetViewAttribures {
    let name: String
    let logo: URL
    let symbol: String
    let avgPrice: String
    let precision: Int
}

struct Commodity: AssetViewAttribures {
    let name: String
    let logo: URL
    let symbol: String
    let avgPrice: String
    let precision: Int
}

struct Fiat: AssetViewAttribures {
    let name: String
    let logo: URL
    let symbol: String
}

protocol AssetViewAttribures {
    var name: String { get }
    var logo: URL { get }
    var symbol: String { get }
}

extension AssetViewAttribures {
    var avgPrice: String { get { return "" } set {} }
    var precision: Int { get{ return 0 } set{} }
}

var type1: AssetViewAttribures = Crypto(name: "name", logo: URL(string: "https://pixabay.com/de/illustrations/online-maus-web-internet-weltweit-523234/")!, symbol: "symbol", avgPrice: "123", precision: 2)

type1.avgPrice // "" instead of "123"
```

Comment: What is `xxx` here? You've explicitly defined setters that don't set anything, so it's the expected result that the properties don't change. Also, you say you have "optional properties", but nothing here is optional.

Comment: It is a type that conforms to AssetViewAttributes protocol

Comment: If I change setter to set { self.avgPrice = newValue } I have a warning Function call causes an infinite recursion

Comment: You should consider including your actual code -- what you have doesn't compile. It seems like you should just get rid of your `extension AssetViewAttributes` altogether and it would solve your issue of your variables not changing.

Comment: the problem is there are another types that also conform to this protocol, but should not have these values in the extension

Comment: Then, once again, I suggest you include your actual code, in the form of a [mre] that represents the issue.

Comment: ok, I updated. Just wanted to keep it cleaner

Comment: I do not want for example `Fiat` struct to have `avgPrice` and `precision` properties in its model

Comment: Do you mean to move the properties out of the extension and mark them optional? If yes, as I mentioned, I do not want to expand the struct model of for instance Fiat struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var type1: AssetViewAttribures = Crypto(name: "name", logo: URL(string: "https://pixabay.com/de/illustrations/online-maus-web-internet-weltweit-523234/")!, symbol: "symbol", avgPrice: "123", precision: 2)

type1.avgPrice
```

This would call the getter declared in the protocol extension, which just returns `""`. This is because `Crypto.avgPrice` has no relation to the `avgPrice` declared in the protocol extension. You can't "override" a member in an extension, because extensions are dispatched statically. The compiler sees that `test` is of type `AssetViewAttributes`, finds the default getter you have declared in the extension, and that's what it will call.

To fix this, you need to add `avgPrice` as a requirement of the protocol:

```
protocol AssetViewAttributes {
    ...
    var avgPrice: String { get }
}
```

This causes Swift to find `avgPrice` declared in the protocol, and dispatches it *dynamically*. If the implementing class happens to implement  `avgPrice`, that implementation will be called. If not, then the default implementation is called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I do not want to move `avgPrice` to the protocol. In this case, I would need to expand the `struct Fiat` with the new property that I do not really want to do

Comment: @ArtiomLemiasheuski No you don't. That's the whole point of having a default in a protocol extension, right? You don't need to change any of the other structs.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood you, but If I add `var avgPrice: String { get }` to the protocol, not to the extension I get the following error: `Type 'Fiat' does not conform to protocol 'AssetViewAttributes'`, meaning I need to add the property to the struct

Comment: Sorry, you meant to move `var avgPrice: String { get }` to the protocol but still have in the extension, right?

Comment: @ArtiomLemiasheuski yes that’s right. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: Just was not aware of it, thanks! so basically, the types that fully conform to the protocol use their own getter, and types like `Fiat` do use the default one from the extension?

Comment: @ArtiomLemiasheuski yes that’s right.